# Преобразование даты из строки в объект

Tags: javascript, дата, преобразование

Ситуация следующая:
нужно хранить полную дату (включая время до миллисекунд), но хранить её можно только в виде строки, объект не подходит и в этом проблема.
Варианта 2 и они не принципиальны.

```html
var date1 = Date.now(); // 1542258559443

var date2 = Date(Date.now); // Thu Nov 15 2018 12:09:19 GMT+0700 (RTZ 6 (зима))
```

Вопрос в том, можно ли как то стандартными методами получить из этих строк дату в виде объекта, как например это делается при получении текущей даты?

```html
var date3 = new Date(); // 2018-11-15T05:09:19.446Z
```

Comment: 2 вариант `Thu Nov 15 2018 12:09:19 GMT+0700 (RTZ 6 (зима))` не хранит миллисекунды. Получение даты `var date3 = new Date(1542258559443);`

Comment: Спасибо! Вариант с var date3 = new Date(1542258559443); подходит. Кстати пробовал так сделать, но передавал туда строку (без преобразования в число), поэтому получал ошибку )

Comment: Оформите как ответ. Может, кому-то в будущем это понадобится!

Answer (score 0):

При вызове [`Date` как функции с одним параметром](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-date-value) будет возвращена **строка** с текущей датой и временем, не зависимо от того, что за параметр был передан.

Для создания объекта нужно использовать функцию `Date`, как конструктор, то есть вместе с оператором `new`.

В этом случае результат будет объект `Date`

```js
console.log(new Date(1542258559443));
console.log(new Date(Date.now())); // не забыть вызвать функцию Date.now, а не просто передать ее
console.log(new Date(Date.now).toString()); // иначе получим Invalid Date
```